# Pin$^+$ and Pin$^−$ structure for manifolds in any dimensions

Tags: manifolds, characteristic-classes, spin-geometry

For an oriented $d$-manifold $M$, we can ask whether the manifold
admits a Spin structure, say, if the transition functions for the
tangent bundle, which take values in $SO(d)$, can be lifted to $\operatorname{Spin}(d)$ while preserving the cocycle condition on triple overlaps of coordinate charts.

For an unoriented $d$-manifold $M$, we can ask whether the manifold
admits Pin$^+$ or Pin$^−$ structures (that is, lifts of transition functions to
either $\operatorname{Pin}^+(d)$ or $\operatorname{Pin}^−(d)$ from $O(d)$. This is analogous to lifting the transition functions to $\operatorname{Spin}(d)$ from $SO(d)$ for the spin manifold).

If the manifold $M$ is orientable, then the conditions for Pin$^+$ or Pin$^−$ structures are the same. So it reduces to the old condition that $M$ admits a Spin structure or not.

Every $2$-dimensional manifold admits a Pin$^−$ structure, but not necessarily a Pin$^+$ structure.

Every $3$-dimensional manifold admits a Pin$^+$ structure, but not necessarily a Pin$^-$ structure.

> Question: For some any other $d$, say $d = 0, 1, 4, 5$ etc. are there statements like: every $d$-dimensional manifold admits a Pin$^-$ structure? Or, every $d$-dimensional manifold admits a Pin$^+$ structure?

P.S. This question has now been asked on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/257891/21564).

Comment: For 2-manifold and 3-manifold, $w_1^2+w_2=0$.  This appears to implies that every 2-manifold and 3-manifold has pin$^-$ structure.

Comment: @Xiao-GangWen: You also need the manifolds to be closed.

Comment: @wonderich: If you accept an answer on the MathOverflow question, one of us could post the accepted answer here as a CW wiki answer so this question would no longer be on the unanswered list. Alternatively, you could delete this question now that it has answers on MathOverflow.

Comment: @Michael Albanese. I think the corrected version should be:

- Every 2-dimensional manifold admits a Pin− structure, but not necessarily a Pin+ structure.

- Every 3-dimensional manifold admits a Pin+ structure, but not necessarily a Pin− structure.

Comment: @wonderich: That's true for closed manifolds, but as I stated in my previous comment, the question you asked has now been answered on MathOverflow, so you should accept an answer there and then one of us can post a wiki version of the accepted answer here so that this question is removed from the unanswered list. If, for some reason, you think the question hasn't been answered, please let me know what's missing.